# Roll not defined - Reference Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently installed a node.js package called [roll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/roll) for my text based game that I am making. Here is my code:

```
var totalHealth = 100;

var swordAttack = roll.roll(d100);
console.log(swordAttack.result);
if (swordAttack.result >=50 ) {
  totalHealth = totalHealth * 0.15
}

console.log(); {
    return swordAttack
};
```

The idea of this code is to roll a number 1-100 if it is more than or equal to 50 it will deal 15 damage if not it will miss. So the error I'm getting is coming through the console when I run the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4CUB.png

I am using VS code if that helps.

Comment: You need to define `roll` before using it, and in your code the `roll` is not defined

Comment: I have just defined it, but I am still getting the error but this time it's: ReferenceError: d100 is not defined.

Comment: d100 is expecting the string

Comment: Do not post images of error dumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working examples

1. first import the  **require** the module
2. fixing the typos

[Try this](https://repl.it/I9mk/0) to see the output press run button

Comment: thanks this helped a lot I rewrote it as a function and it's working perferctly

Answer (score 1):

> First require your module and then use it

```
var roll = require('roll'),
  roll = new roll();
```